# Should I be using .on() or .click() to attach an event handler?

Tags: jquery

Assuming I just want to attach a simple click handler to an element, I've always done this:

```
$("#mydiv").click(function() { ... });
```

Looking at the JQuery docs, it seems that [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the "recommended" way to attach event handlers and replaces `.bind()`, `.delegate()` and `.live()`:

> *As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required
>   for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery
>   event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live().*

And in the docs for [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) it says:

> *This method is a shortcut for .bind('click', handler) in the first two variations, and .trigger('click') in the third.*

So this implies that `.click()` is using `.bind()` which will be deprecated and replaced by `.on()`, right? Or is the implication that `.click()` will stick around, but it will at some point become a shortcut for `.on("click")`?

Basically, my question is this... When writing JQuery code today, should I use:

```
Variant 1: $("#mydiv").click(function() { ... });
```

or:

```
Variant 2: $("#mydiv").on("click", function() { ... });
```

?

Comment: You don't  have to worry about legacy code, it's highly unlikely they're gonna remove the click shorthand completely. The .on() handler is just a more efficient way of attaching event handlers, from being able to attach multiple event-handlers at the same time, to adding extra information to a mapped event!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would use `on()` for all event bindings from jQuery 1.7+.

It means there's no ambiguity between elements which are added dynamically and those available on page load.

Also, as you state, `click()` (and other event shortcuts) are converted to `on("event", function() { ... });` by jQuery anyway, so it saves a step in the process - not that this makes a noticeable difference of course.

And finally, `on("click")` reads better in my opinion.

Comment: The docs state that .click() is converted to .bind(), not to .on(). That's why I'm confused.

Comment: In 1.7+ `click()` is converted to `on()`. I guess they havent updated the docs yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer clear Rory. I looked through the JQuery 1.7 source to confirm - not that I don't trust you ;) The .click() call is in fact converted to .bind() as the docs say. But .bind() is in turn converted to .on(). So yes, you're absolutely right.